# how to use one more indeterminate checkbox column in react-table

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, use-effect, react-table, use-ref

I'm displaying user data using react-table with select all checkbox. but i want to add one more checkbox column to change active/inactive status. i have added status check box but when i select any status checkbox then 1st column checkbox also get selected.

https://codesandbox.io/s/condescending-lewin-fcukr?file=/src/App.js

[image]

```
import React from "react";
import styled from "styled-components";
import { useTable, usePagination, useRowSelect } from "react-table";

import makeData from "./makeData";

const Styles = styled.div`
  padding: 1rem;

  table {
    border-spacing: 0;
    border: 1px solid black;

    tr {
      :last-child {
        td {
          border-bottom: 0;
        }
      }
    }

    th,
    td {
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0.5rem;
      border-bottom: 1px solid black;
      border-right: 1px solid black;

      :last-child {
        border-right: 0;
      }
    }
  }

  .pagination {
    padding: 0.5rem;
  }
`;

const IndeterminateCheckbox = React.forwardRef(
  ({ indeterminate, ...rest }, ref) => {
    const defaultRef = React.useRef();
    const resolvedRef = ref || defaultRef;

    React.useEffect(() => {
      resolvedRef.current.indeterminate = indeterminate;
    }, [resolvedRef, indeterminate]);

    return (
      <>
        <input type="checkbox" ref={resolvedRef} {...rest} />
      </>
    );
  }
);
const IndeterminateCheckbox2 = React.forwardRef(
  ({ indeterminate, ...rest }, ref) => {
    const defaultRef = React.useRef();
    const resolvedRef = ref || defaultRef;

    React.useEffect(() => {
      resolvedRef.current.indeterminate = indeterminate;
    }, [resolvedRef, indeterminate]);

    return (
      <>
        <input type="checkbox" name="status" ref={resolvedRef} {...rest} />
      </>
    );
  }
);

function Table({ columns, data }) {
  // Use the state and functions returned from useTable to build your UI
  const {
    getTableProps,
    getTableBodyProps,
    headerGroups,
    prepareRow,
    page, // Instead of using 'rows', we'll use page,
    // which has only the rows for the active page

    // The rest of these things are super handy, too ;)
    canPreviousPage,
    canNextPage,
    pageOptions,
    pageCount,
    gotoPage,
    nextPage,
    previousPage,
    setPageSize,
    selectedFlatRows,
    state: { pageIndex, pageSize, selectedRowIds }
  } = useTable(
    {
      columns,
      data
    },
    usePagination,
    useRowSelect,
    (hooks) => {
      hooks.visibleColumns.push((columns) => [
        // Let's make a column for selection
        {
          id: "selection",
          // The header can use the table's getToggleAllRowsSelectedProps method
          // to render a checkbox
          Header: ({ getToggleAllPageRowsSelectedProps }) => (
            <div>
              <IndeterminateCheckbox {...getToggleAllPageRowsSelectedProps()} />
            </div>
          ),
          // The cell can use the individual row's getToggleRowSelectedProps method
          // to the render a checkbox
          Cell: ({ row }) => (
            <div>
              <IndeterminateCheckbox {...row.getToggleRowSelectedProps()} />
            </div>
          )
        },
        ...columns
      ]);
    }
  );

  // Render the UI for your table
  return (
    <>
      <pre>
        <code>
          {JSON.stringify(
            {
              pageIndex,
              pageSize,
              pageCount,
              canNextPage,
              canPreviousPage
            },
            null,
            2
          )}
        </code>
      </pre>
      <table {...getTableProps()}>
        <thead>
          {headerGroups.map((headerGroup) => (
            <tr {...headerGroup.getHeaderGroupProps()}>
              {headerGroup.headers.map((column) => (
                <th {...column.getHeaderProps()}>{column.render("Header")}</th>
              ))}
            </tr>
          ))}
        </thead>
        <tbody {...getTableBodyProps()}>
          {page.map((row, i) => {
            prepareRow(row);
            return (
              <tr {...row.getRowProps()}>
                {row.cells.map((cell) => {
                  return (
                    <td {...cell.getCellProps()}>{cell.render("Cell")}</td>
                  );
                })}
              </tr>
            );
          })}
        </tbody>
      </table>
      {/* 
        Pagination can be built however you'd like. 
        This is just a very basic UI implementation:
      */}
      <div className="pagination">
        <button onClick={() => gotoPage(0)} disabled={!canPreviousPage}>
          {"<<"}
        </button>{" "}
        <button onClick={() => previousPage()} disabled={!canPreviousPage}>
          {"<"}
        </button>{" "}
        <button onClick={() => nextPage()} disabled={!canNextPage}>
          {">"}
        </button>{" "}
        <button onClick={() => gotoPage(pageCount - 1)} disabled={!canNextPage}>
          {">>"}
        </button>{" "}
        <span>
          Page{" "}
          <strong>
            {pageIndex + 1} of {pageOptions.length}
          </strong>{" "}
        </span>
        <span>
          | Go to page:{" "}
          <input
            type="number"
            defaultValue={pageIndex + 1}
            onChange={(e) => {
              const page = e.target.value ? Number(e.target.value) - 1 : 0;
              gotoPage(page);
            }}
            style={{ width: "100px" }}
          />
        </span>{" "}
        <select
          value={pageSize}
          onChange={(e) => {
            setPageSize(Number(e.target.value));
          }}
        >
          {[10, 20, 30, 40, 50].map((pageSize) => (
            <option key={pageSize} value={pageSize}>
              Show {pageSize}
            </option>
          ))}
        </select>
        <pre>
          <code>
            {JSON.stringify(
              {
                selectedRowIds: selectedRowIds,
                "selectedFlatRows[].original": selectedFlatRows.map(
                  (d) => d.original
                )
              },
              null,
              2
            )}
          </code>
        </pre>
      </div>
    </>
  );
}

function App() {
  const columns = React.useMemo(
    () => [
      {
        Header: "Name",
        columns: [
          {
            Header: "First Name",
            accessor: "firstName"
          },
          {
            Header: "Last Name",
            accessor: "lastName"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        Header: "Info",
        columns: [
          {
            Header: "Age",
            accessor: "age"
          },
          {
            Header: "Visits",
            accessor: "visits"
          },
          {
            Header: "Status",
            accessor: "status",
            Cell: ({ row }) => (
              <div>
                <IndeterminateCheckbox2 {...row.getToggleRowSelectedProps()} />
              </div>
            )
          },
          {
            Header: "Profile Progress",
            accessor: "progress"
          }
        ]
      }
    ],
    []
  );

  const data = React.useMemo(() => makeData(100000), []);

  return (
    <Styles>
      <Table columns={columns} data={data} />
    </Styles>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: You should post the code and not a link

Comment: @RaduDiță check now

Comment: @RaduDiță it not working. 1st column checkbox should not inter depend on status column checkbox.

Answer (score 1):

Use React If are you use Uesmemo hooks and pass in the column.

```
const columns = React.useMemo(
() => [
  {
    Header: "data",
    accessor: "data",
    isVisible: true,
    disableFilters: true,
    Cell: ({ value, row, column }) => {
      if (row.index === 0) {
        return (
          <div>
            <Input typy="check"
              value={data}
              onChange={(e) => {
                handleChange(e, "data");
              }}
              
              disabled={false}
            />
            
          </div>
        );
      } else {
        return `${row.original}`;
      }
    },
  },
```

Comment: any one have solution for it ? @kuldeep